# SQL Join :: Fetching records outside join condition

Tags: join, hive, hiveql

I have 2 tables A and B
**A**
[image]

**B**
[image]

The requirement is to join both tables using id column and along with that, if the fetched name value is having another record with a different id, that record should also be fetched. Like the below screenshot.
**Output :**
[image]

Requirements

- Table B is in the size of TBs. single join of both tables will be
  preferable
- query needs to be executed on hive

Comment: Can there be more than 2 records with the same name?

Comment: it can have more records. table is huge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with HiveQL, but with regular SQL, you'll need to join table B to itself a second time as part of the query.

```
select
    b_name.id, b_name.name
from
    #table_A a                  
    join #table_B b             -- This table gets the "name" value for lookup
        on (a.id=b.id)
    join #table_B b_name        -- This is the table you want to pull your "output" from
        on (b.name=b_name.name)
```

This query essentially says that you need to find the value of the "name" column in table B, where there is a matching ID in table A, and then lookup all the rows with that name value in table B.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But in the real world scenario, the table B is in the size of TBs. So the second join will be costly. That is the reason why i posted sample data instead of actual tables.

Comment: Have you tried it? It shouldn't be that costly if A is small, names don't occur that many times, there are proper indexes (if that applies to Hive). Anyway, you will have to find all the names, so there is not really another way. Maybe it supports some `where exists (subselect) syntax, but it's effectively the same amount of work.

Comment: in this scenario, will the query scan the whole table twice? Assuming that there's no index.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Unfortunately this is the most efficient way that you can do this with basic SQL (assuming proper indexes are in place). Hopefully somebody more familiar with Hadoop will come along, who knows some Hadoop-specific big-data magic functionality. But ultimately, you will need to do two separate lookups on the table.

Comment: @OptimusPrime If there is no index, then the queries will perform a table scan for every scan it does (in this case, it will do two table scans, as you mentioned). If you have TBs of data, indexes are pretty essential...

Comment: Apparently [indexes are removed in Hive 3.0](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Indexing), but a materialized view with automatic rewriting could have similar results.

Comment: Indexes even when it was there, it wasnt that effective and maintaining it is still costly. I was looking for some magic functionality like oracle connect_by_prior or similar item where it can travel through the connection. just a thought..

Comment: @OptimusPrime I hope that you can find something! I would suggest updating your question to make it clear that you're not looking for a regular solution, but rather one that is specific to Hadoop, and how it processes TBs of data. Otherwise a potential answerer might simply see the answers from GolezTrol and I, and assume that your question has already been answered.

Comment: Connect by prior in Oracle is a very expensive operation. The fact that you mention a certain table once in a query doesn't guarantee that it's faster.

Comment: @RToyo Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can join the same table multiple times. So in the query below, b1 will give you all the names for the ids in A, and b2 is joined by name, to get you all the extra ids that are not in A.

```
select
  b2.*
from
  A 
  inner join B b1 on b1.id = A.id
  inner join B b2 on b2.name = b1.name
```